# Liquid filter to strip HTML comments

Tags: comments, jekyll, liquid, strip

Is there any way to remove HTML comments from a string using Liquid? Here is my current code:

```
{{ post.content | strip | xml_escape }}
```

Is there any way to do something like:

```
{{ post.content | strip | xml_escape | strip_comments }}
```

That removes all HTML comments? I could do this with RegEx and replace (`/<!--.-->/g`), but liquid doesn't support that.

It is for an RSS feed, so I cannot use any JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this. You could, however, use liquid `{% comment %}`  tags inside of your post instead.

Comment: `{% comment %}<!-- My HTML comment -->{% endcomment %}` works for me. A Jekyll Filter would be nice ... which drops the `<!--` and `-->` elements

Answer (score 3):

To remove all HTML comments from a string using Liquid, you could try:

```
{{ post.content | strip_html | escape }}
```

Comment: This also strips other HTML tags.